# Earliest preload for an image in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, css, image, performance, css-sprites

What is the earliest possible time in an HTML page load sequence that an image request can be issued?

A site I am involved with is switching to using sprite pages. The sprite page is potentially very large, and the overall page load time of the first page greatly benefits from this request being issued early by the browser. The pages also include heavy CSS and JS loads and it would be terrible only to initiate the sprite-page load after these are complete.

The quickest overall load time which I've found is to create an ultra-short CSS file, referred to early in the HTML head section, which references the image in a class. This typically initiates the image request before the other CSS and JS have finished loading (number of connections permitting) in modern browsers. Other techniques seem to delay at least until the CSS is all loaded before initiating the image request.

I dislike this technique, however, as it introduces one more round-trip and one more file than seems necessary, which might add 50ms-100ms or so to the load time compared to a technique which initiates the image request direct from the HTML. However, referring to the image in the HTML body, etc, seem to cause the request to wait until the head CSS is all loaded. And the more obvious solutions -- not sweating it, referring to it naturally in the main CSS, including as an image in the body -- are all robustly slower by around 200ms-300ms in this (bloated) application.

Maybe there is a good way to reference an image extremely early in an HTML head that might cause at least some modern browsers to load it extremely early? (Some special, weird kind of link tag, maybe?

Any good online explanation of modern load-order would also be of benefit (but not an answer to the question).

We have a good, robust load-time test based on headless browsers which allows us to test load-times to 10ms accuracy with a variety of artificial latencies and bandwidths on a realistic profile of our pages, and these differences are statistically significant. So I'm happy to take untested proposals in answers and put it through the framework.

[I'm aware that in many cases data-urls in CSS and icons as dingbats in WOFFs are better techniques than sprite-pages, but that's not true in all cases of all images (which we have the data to show), and this use of sprite-pages is part of a migration path for a complex application].

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to inline that CSS part into your HTML, e.g:

```html
<head>
  <title>(...)</title>
  <style>
    /* your inline style */
  </style>
  <!-- other link tags, maybe scripts, etc -->
</head>
```

Comment: That's certainly worth trying. I'll give that a go (with other answers if there are any) and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script at the very top of your HTML page just after the `<title>` tag that will perform an asynchronous HTTP Request:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script>
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
   xhr.open( "GET", "http://your-sprite-page", true )
   xhr.send()
  </script>
  ...
```

Anyway, depending on vendor implementation of async requests, maybe the best way is to include an `<img hidden>` tag in the body part.

*Dev Tools* timeline is your friend.

Comment: That's a bit ugly, but if it's the fastest way to do it, that's no bar. I'll give it a go, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Please see comments from [Supersharp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4600982/supersharp) below which correct my initial use of rel="prefetch", suggesting  rel="import"  instead.

Also [this document](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#performance) suggests using the async attribute with rel="import" to prevent blocking. So combining these suggestions would give

```
<head>  
...  
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/large-background-image.jpg" async>
...  
</head>
```

Good luck!

Comment: That's neat. I'll give it a go, thank you! Always good if there's a proper standardsy way of doing things.

Comment: I don't think the download will be prioritized over other subsequent download calls. The `prefetch` may be launched only when the browser is idle.

Comment: Hey @Supersharp, I think you are correct, thanks for picking this up, I've updated my answer

Comment: Maybe using instead `rel="import"` could work (but only on Chrome and Opera).

Comment: Another good suggestion @Supersharp, thank you. I updated my answer again ;)